# Anyway to track out two different voices within 1 audio file?

Tags: audio, logic-pro, sound-editing, voices

I have a podcast audio file with 2 voices, each speaking 1 at a time, and I need to track these out into two different files. I have logic, and I'm curious if there is any quicker way to separate the two voices while keeping the correct timing without going through the entire audio file and doing it manually!

Answer (score 1):

One thing that might be helpful is to use what I believe is called "strip silence", where logic will analyze the audio file and break it into chunks by removing any portions that don't have any audio above the threshold you set (I haven't used this in a long time, so that may not be the name of the function but it's something like that).  From there, you'd still have to listen through everything and move the different regions to a separate track.  I'd probably go about this by using the strip silence function, listening back and shift+click each regions where one of the voices is talking, then click and drag to another track at the end.  You could make this quicker by increasing the playback speed.  You'll have to be careful to make sure that no voices begins talking quickly enough after the other stops that it doesn't create an additional region.

Comment: Strip Silence is a Protools function. Just cuts up tracks, doesn't sort them and doesn't handle overlaps. As per below, this is an elbow-grease job,

Comment: There is definitely a strip silence function in Logic. I have never used pro tools. It wouldn’t handle overlaps but OP directly states that each speaks one at a time. It doesn’t sort them but I specifically mentioned this in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

No. There isn't.  Elbow grease is your only option unfortunately.